# Removing duplicates if paired adjacently

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Deleting any pair of **adjacent** letters with same value. For example, string "aabcc" would become either "aab" or "bcc" after  operation.

Sample input = aaabccddd

Sample output = abd

Confused how to iterate the list or the string in a way to match the duplicates and removing them, here is the way I am trying and I know it is wrong.

```
S = input()
removals = []

for i in range(0, len(S)):
    if i + 1 >= len(S):
        break

    elif S[i] == S[i + 1]:
        removals.append(i)    
        # removals is to store all the indexes that are to be deleted.
        removals.append(i + 1)
        i += 1
    print(i)
Array = list(S)
set(removals)    #removes duplicates from removals

for j in range(0, len(removals)):
    Array.pop(removals[j])    # Creates IndexOutOfRange error
```

This is a problem from Hackerrank: [Super Reduced String](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string)

Comment: Why `aab`? That's `aa` is an adjacent pair in your input sample.

Comment: You are not explaining the Hackerrank problem very well. There the sample is `aabcc` (2 times `c`, not 3), and they are talking about **one operation** in a series.

Comment: aab because it is removing cc that is one operation and in another operation it will remove aa and forms b. Also corrected that one, link is only provided because I could not explain the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing paired letters can be reduced to reducing runs of letters to an empty sequence if there are an even number of them, 1 if there are an odd number. `aaaaaa` becomes empty, `aaaaa` is reduced to `a`.

To do this on any sequence, use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and count the group size:

```
# only include a value if their consecutive count is odd
[v for v, group in groupby(sequence) if sum(1 for _ in group) % 2]
```

then repeat until the size of the sequence no longer changes:

```
prev = len(sequence) + 1
while len(sequence) < prev:
    prev = len(sequence)
    sequence = [v for v, group in groupby(sequence) if sum(1 for _ in group) % 2]
```

However, since Hackerrank gives you *text* it'd be faster if you did this with a regular expression:

```
import re

even = re.compile(r'(?:([a-z])\1)+')

prev = len(text) + 1
while len(text) < prev:
    prev = len(text)
    text = even.sub(r'', text)
```

`[a-z]` in a regex matches a lower-case letter, (..)`groups that match, and`\1`references the first match and will only match if that letter was repeated.`(?:...)+`asks for repeats of the same two characters.`re.sub()` replaces all those patterns with empty text.

The regex approach is good enough to pass that Hackerrank challenge.

Comment: Thanks Regular expression makes it easy and fast because it does not have to iterate.

Comment: @YashAgarwal: Actually the stack based approach is much faster since it's **O(n)** time complexity. When N=100 as in Hackerrank challenge it doesn't matter but if there's string with let's say 1000000 characters you'd see enormous difference in worst case performance.

Comment: @niemmi: which is why Hackerrank gives those numbers :-) At that low `N`, repeating the regex a few times (which does not have any backtracking issues) is going to beat out a stack loop on constant time per step.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Even with N=100 it depends completely on input. In some cases regex is about 5x faster than stack but in worst case scenario regex takes about 10x of stack based approach.

Comment: @niemmi: thanks for adding benchmarks, that's interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack in order to achieve **O(n)** time complexity. Iterate over the characters in a string and for each character check if the top of stack contains the same character. In case it does pop the character from stack and move to next item. Otherwise push the character to the stack. Whatever remains in the stack is the result:

```
s = 'aaabccddd'
stack = []

for c in s:
    if stack and stack[-1] == c:
        stack.pop()
    else:
        stack.append(c)

print ''.join(stack) if stack else 'Empty String' # abd
```

**Update** Based on the discussion I ran couple of tests to measure the speed of regex and stack based solutions with input length of `100`. Tests were run on Python 2.7 on Windows 8:

```
All same
Regex: 0.0563033799756
Stack: 0.267807865445
Nothing to remove
Regex: 0.075074750044
Stack: 0.183467329017
Worst case
Regex: 1.9983200193
Stack: 0.196362265609
Alphabet
Regex: 0.0759905517997
Stack: 0.182778728207
```

Code used for benchmarking:

```
import re
import timeit

def reduce_regexp(text):
    even = re.compile(r'(?:([a-z])\1)+')

    prev = len(text) + 1
    while len(text) < prev:
        prev = len(text)
        text = even.sub(r'', text)

    return text

def reduce_stack(s):
    stack = []

    for c in s:
        if stack and stack[-1] == c:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            stack.append(c)

    return ''.join(stack)


CASES = [
    ['All same', 'a' * 100],
    ['Nothing to remove', 'ab' * 50],
    ['Worst case', 'ab' * 25 + 'ba' * 25],
    ['Alphabet', ''.join([chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(25)] * 4)]
]

for name, case in CASES:
    print(name)
    res = timeit.timeit('reduce_regexp(case)',
                        setup='from __main__ import reduce_regexp, case; import re',
                        number=10000)
    print('Regex: {}'.format(res))
    res = timeit.timeit('reduce_stack(case)',
                        setup='from __main__ import reduce_stack, case',
                        number=10000)
    print('Stack: {}'.format(res))
```

Comment: The code is working fine but I am unable to understand the if part, give me some time to figure it out. Thanks your code looks elegant.

Comment: @YashAgarwal: First part of `if` checks if `stack` contains any items since in Python empty sequence is considered `False` in boolean context. Second part that only gets evaluated in case `stack` is non-empty returns the last item from `stack` and compares it against current character.

Comment: Got it, it is done in such a good way, Thanks, Understood that for problems like these we have to use the list with stack operations.

Comment: Don't use `time.clock()`; use the `timeit` module to do proper timing trials (as it'll pick the right clock for your platform, disable GC, etc). `from timeit import timeit` and `duration = timeit('f(case)', 'from __main__ import case, reduce_regexp as f', number=10000)`, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Updated, doesn't change the results in one way or another. The only change are the numbers in worst case scenario since I fixed the input length, ratio remains the same though.

Comment: I didn't expect them to, just pointing out there is a better and accepted method of doing time trials.

Comment: `'Alphabet'` could be generated with `string.ascii_lowercase[:-1] * 4` rather than generate the alphabet with `ord()`.